# How to assign a static IP to a Computer in Active Directory

Tags: windows, networking, ip, dhcp, active-directory

I'd like to know how you can assign a static IP address to a **computer** using Active Directory.

I know it is possible with a user using the Dial-in tab, but doing it on a computer has no effect (unless I have missed a specific policy parameter).
Currently I am using DHCP reservations, but it requires having IP addresses in the DHCP range and writing down MAC address to type it on the server.

I am trying to find a way that wouldn't require the use of the obscure MAC adresses by using AD computer names.
Also, I'd like to have my DHCP range cover only the addresses actually used by DHCP clients and not rely on exclusions.

My AD forest and domain have a functionnal level of Windows Server 2008 R2 (because I have Win 7 computers) but I'm using Windows Server 2012.

Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: *I'd like to have my DHCP range cover only the addresses actually used by DHCP clients*...IP address assignment is done either manually (static assignment on node) or automatically (dynamic assignment, e.g. via DHCP).  Unless you're configuring IPs directly on your PCs, your machines **are** DHCP clients.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your use of DHCP is already the best way to assign address.  It's not possible to use Active Directory in an of itself to assign IP addresses because a computer must have an IP address *before* it can communicate directly with AD.

There's no way around the involvement of MAC addresses in dynamic IP address assignment. Until a computer has an IP address, it is effectively unable to communicate via the IP protocol (OSI [layer 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_layer)), instead relying on broadcasts and [MAC addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address).  To get an IP address without one being statically configured on the machine, there must be a service on the network that assigns IP addresses based on MAC address.  Typically this is DHCP, though other services exist.

Comment: I have experienced a similar situation where the DHCP is configured to only assign fixed IPs to domain members based on MAC adress, but to become a domain member, the client needs an IP. As this was a migration from static to dynamic IPs, I solved it by using a single static IP for each client, then join it, then switch network settings back to dynamic (this might be done by GPO or similar, but it was not much effort as you are already in front of the client for the join.

Answer (score 1):

Yoy can try to modify the IpHostNumber (Contains the IP address of the host in dotted decimal notation, omitting the leading zeros.) attribute in Properties of Host - Tab Attribute Editor. Search for this attribute and edit with the IP that you need.

Regards
P.D Sorry for my english ;)

Comment: Sorry, didn't work for me. I tried to set 3229841418 (192.131.120.10) and got DHCP's 192.131.120.100 when checking in Network center.

Answer (score 0):

Some other DHCP software can set reservations on other attributes of a DHCP discovery packet than the MAC address.  For example our software [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) can set a reservation based on the computer name (NetBIOS name).

As long as you set your DHCP server to assign your AD DNS to clients, it doesn't break your AD either, and in fact we use WinGate DHCP in our Active Directory here.

Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who are the authors of WinGate.